# I'm having some trouble trying to get my script to change a element

Tags: javascript

I have a built a small form on a Drupal site with the following code:

```
<form id="form">
    <button class="btn calc" id="calculator" onclick="return false">Submit</button>
    <div class="calcAnswer">£ <span id="result">no value</span></div>
</form>
```

I would like to use JavaScript to automatically replace the #result element with a value once the button is clicked.

I'm trying this code (but can't seem to get it working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $("#calculator").click(function () {
        $("#result").replaceWith('<span id="result">A new value</span>');
    });
});
```

I have been testing in a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/NFQpw/8/) but am getting nowhere.

Comment: Add `jQuery library` to your fiddle first  See: http://jsfiddle.net/NFQpw/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem with your fiddle is that you have "No-Library (pure JS)" specified.  You need to include jQuery, and your script will work as expected (on the left bar, under "Frameworks & Extensions", select a version of jQuery).  There's nothing wrong with your jQuery.

That said, I agree with @Stijn Martens, using `.html('A new value')` is cleaner; there's no reason to use `.replaceWith` in this instance.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jammerwoch/NFQpw/12/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the html inside the `#result` span. Using the `.html()` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $("#calculator").click(function () {
        $("#result").html('A new value');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Stijntjhe/NFQpw/10/

Comment: Actually the OP's code is perfectly correct, however they had not included the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

try this one. just include JS: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/makypl/NFQpw/9/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){
    $("#calculator").click(function () {
        $("#result").replaceWith('<span id="result">A new value</span>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working, but you're testing with pure `Javascript`, not `jQuery`

set on `Frameworks & Extensions` in the left menu the option `jQuery 1.10.1`

and it will work